# Plotting the z(x,y) = 0 plane with Plot3D. How can I make the Mesh in polar coordinates?

Tags: plotting, mesh, 3d-printing

If I

> Plot3D[0,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]

I get the desired z(x,y) = 0 plane which I want to plot, however with a cartesian mesh drawn on it. I would instead like the mesh to be in polar coordinates. How can I do that?

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Plot3D[0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},MeshFunctions -> {(Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2]&), ArcTan[#1, #2] & } , MaxRecursion -> 4, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Feeling stupid...very nice  +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Here some approaches:

1. Using [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html)

   ```
        Plot3D[0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {(#1^2 + #2^2 &), #1 - #2 &, #1 + #2 &, 
        #1 &, #2 &},
        Mesh -> {Range[10]^2, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
        PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
   ```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

2. Using [`ParametricPLot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPLot3D.html)

   ```
     ParametricPlot3D[u {Cos[v], Sin[v], 0}, {u, 0, 10}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
   ```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**See Ulrich Neumann answer for better MeshFunctions**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47VNv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRQ55.png